# Много ли едят памяти неиспользуемые методы в объектах JS?

Tags: javascript, классы, объекты, шаблоны-проектирования, память

Всем привет!

У меня есть метод класс element:

```js
class Element{
  constructor(element){
    this.element = element;
  }
  setVisible(){
    this.element.setAttribute('style', 'visibility:visible;');
  }
  setHidden(){
    this.element.setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden;');
  }
  setParrent(parrent){
    this.parrent = parrent;
  }
  setServerScript(script){
    this.script = script;
  }
  //и т.д. очень много методов штук 100
}
```

От него наследуются различные классы для `DOM` элементов, в объектах которых, в последствии, используется лишь процентов 20% тех методов, заложенных в родительском классе.

Вопрос - плохо ли это с точки зрения организации кода? Нужно ли применять в таком случае паттерн легковес, например?

И второй вопрос - кушают ли эти неиспользуемые методы память? И, если, да - как узнать сколько? Желательно с помощью google wev tools.

Спасибо!

Comment: По моему, это будет экономия на спичках

Comment: gil9red, да, возможно. А как оценить сколько спичек мы сэкономим? Я сейчас читаю мануал по web tools, но если есть подсказка - было бы очень кстати)))

Comment: Насколько я знаю, при прототипном наследовании(а у нас он здесь) методы создаются в единственном экземпляре. Соответственно, можете создавать сколько угодно инстансов - методы в памяти место занимать больше не станут.